# Opencart Paypal Express Checkout L_ERRORCODE0=10486

Tags: opencart, paypal

When I making payment, keep getting error code 10486, this message from Error Log. When I making payment, I choose not require login option and then using credit card, but debit card has no issue, only credit card. Paypal prompt me "We're sorry, the card issuer declined your purchase using card Visa x-xxxx. Please enter a new credit or debit card to continue payment." OR after clicking pay now, it is redirect back to the website, but payment is not successful sometimes is working not everytime, very weird. I've check many website, but no solution, I did try paypal payment standard module transaction still fail, but no error logs found.

And I've check billing address, CC expired date, CC secret number everything correct and my CC is valid.

OpenCart version: V 1.5.6
Paypal Acc Type: Business
Modules: Paypal Express checkout (pre-installed one)

Anyone experience can help? Many thanks.

Comment: Is this using the *sandbox* or *live* mode?

Comment: Configuration from opencart show Live mode. Where to check from paypal?

Comment: So switch to *sandbox* and test the card or payments at all in sandbox mode first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 10486 notifies merchants when a buyer's payment failed due to a bad funding method (typically an invalid or maxed out credit card). If the merchant receives this error code from PayPal, the Merchant can re-direct the buyer back to the PayPal page to select an alternate payment source or add a new funding instrument.

Error 10486 is documented under: 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

I hope this answer in full to your question.

Comment: but i am pretty sure my credit card has no issue and info are correct. I did use the same CC and info to others website has no issue. They are using paypal as well.

Comment: Hi Falcon, I'd recommend to consult your card issuer or PayPal Customer Support to verify why the CC payments were declined.  With regard to 10486 error please consult the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/